Why does OpenAI Whisper return "None"?
I'm trying to transcribe an MP3 file using OpenAI’s Whisper model, but the transcriptions.create() method consistently returns None. I’ve tried different MP3 files, converted them to WAV, updated the OpenAI library, and added error handling, but I still can’t figure out the issue.
Here’s my code:
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    api_key="MYAPIKEY"
)

audio_file = open("speech.mp3", "rb")
transcript = client.audio.transcriptions.create(
    file=audio_file,
    model="whisper-1",
    response_format="verbose_json",
    timestamp_granularities=["segment"]
)

print(transcript)

I’ve confirmed that:

The API key is valid.
I’m using OpenAI Python library version X.X.X.
I’ve tested both MP3 and WAV formats.
The MP3 file is valid (checked using ffmpeg).

The response always returns None without any exceptions. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

The maximum file size for the OpenAI Whisper model is 25 MB, and the maximum duration is 30 seconds. Check the audio file, if it does exceed 25 MB, break it into chunks and send.

My audio file is 9 MB

Hmm, that's very strange. By the way do you have enough credits in your openAI account?
